# Access user options in background.js in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to access chrome.storage.sync where I store some user options in my background.js but the asynchronous nature of chrome.storage.sync.get is causing me issues.

If I try and use chrome.storage.sync.get within my chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener the callback isn't quick enough for the function to use it.

I have tried adding the user options as a global variable within background.js but it appears to me that that value doesn't persist.

Anyone else using user options in background.js?

```js
function getoption(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    radarpref: 'nothing',
  }, function(items) {
  console.log(items.radarpref);
  return items.radarpref;
    
  });

}
var hold = getoption();
console.log (hold) //this returns hold value

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {

    //this doesn't work - yet
   console.log('i dont see the hold');
 console.log(hold) //hold not returned when callback ran
  ...
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to synchronously use settings from any async storage - the best way to do it is to cache it.

You need to load the settings to the cache on `background.js` start and then you need to update cache each time `chrome.storage.onChanged` event triggered.

Example how to do it:

**manifest.js**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Settings Online demo",
    "description": "Settings Online demo",    
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "852a5a44289192c3cd3d71e06fdcdb43b1437971@j2me.ws"
        }
    },
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "options_ui": {
        "page":"properties.html",
        "chrome_style": true
    }
}
```

Note that you need to have non-temporary application id if you need to work it on firefox, `<all_urls>` permission is needed to get access to any url request processing.

**background.js**

```
((storage) => {
    let settings = (function(properties) {

        // Save settings
        this.set = (properties,ok) => {
            for(key in properties || {}){
                this[key]=properties[key];
            }
            storage.set(
                properties
            ,() => {
                ok(settings);
            });
        };

        //Default values processing
        for(key in properties || {}){
            this[key]=properties[key];
        }

        // Initial settings read
        storage.get(properties,(properties) => {
            for(key in properties){
                this[key]=properties[key];
            }
        });


        // Listen settings change and cache it
        chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((msg) => {
            for(key in msg){
                this[key]=msg[key].newValue;
            }
        });

        return this;
    }).call({},{"property":"default","name":"me"})

    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
      function(info) {
       // Update and persist settings
       settings.set({"lastRequest":info},()=>{console.log("Settings saved")});
       console.log('Catch', settings.name,settings.property);
    },{urls:["https://*/*"]});
})(chrome.storage.sync || chrome.storage.local);
```

Note that I use `chrome.storage.sync || chrome.storage.local` because some browsers (Opera, mobile browsers) do not support sync-storage, but support local storage.

And the property page to see how can property changes are processing:
**properties.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="properties.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Property:<input id="property" type="text"></label>
        <input id="save-properties" value="save" type="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

**properties.js**

```
((storage) => {
    let saveOptions = () => {
        let property = document.getElementById("property").value;

        storage.set({
            "property": property
        },() => {
            window.close();
        });
    }

    let restoreOptions = () => {
        storage.get({
            "property": "default"
        }, (properties) => {
            document.getElementById("property").value = properties.property;
        });
        document.getElementById("save-properties").addEventListener("click", saveOptions);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreOptions);
})(chrome.storage.sync || chrome.storage.local);
```

That's all :)

P.S> This solution has a weak point: if your app is settings-sensitive and can't work with default settings, or you need to be sure that you're using custom settings on start - you need to delay background.js start while settings are not loaded. You may to it with callback or with promise:

**background.js - wait while settings will be loaded with callback**

```
((storage) => {
    let settings = (function(properties) {

        // Update settings
        this.set = (properties,ok) => {
            for(key in properties || {}){
                this[key]=properties[key];
            }
            storage.set(
                properties
            ,() => {
                ok(settings);
            });
        };

        //Default values processing
        for(key in properties || {}){
            this[key]=properties[key];
        }

        // Listen settings change and cache it
        chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((msg) => {
            for(key in msg){
                this[key]=msg[key].newValue;
            }
        });

        // Initial settings read
        storage.get(properties,(properties) => {
            for(key in properties){
                this[key]=properties[key];
            }
            mainLoop();
        });

        return this;
    }).call({},{"property":"default","name":"me"})

    let mainLoop = () => {

        //.. all you settings-sensitive code
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
          function(info) {
            // Update settings and persist it       
            settings.set({"lastRequest":info},()=>{console.log("Settings saved")});
           console.log('Catch', settings.name,settings.property);
        },{urls:["https://*/*"]});
    };

})(chrome.storage.sync || chrome.storage.local);
```

**background.js - wait while settings will be loaded with promise**

```
((storage) => {
    let settings = ((properties) => {

        this.set = (properties) => {
            for(key in properties || {}){
                this[key]=properties[key];
            }
            return new Promise((ok,err) => {
                storage.set(
                    properties
                ,() => {
                    ok(settings);
                });
            });
        };

        return new Promise((ok,err) => {
            //Default values processing
            for(key in properties || {}){
                this[key]=properties[key];
            }

            // Listen settings change and cache it
            chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((msg) => {
                for(key in msg){
                    this[key]=msg[key].newValue;
                }
            });

            // Initial settings read
            storage.get(properties,(properties) => {
                for(key in properties){
                    this[key]=properties[key];
                }
                ok(this);
            });
        });
    }).call({},{"property":"default","name":"me"}).then((settings) => {
        //.. all you settings-sensitive code

        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
          function(info) {
            // Update settings and persist it       
            settings.set({"lastRequest":info}).then(()=>{console.log("Settings saved")});
            console.log('Catch', settings.name,settings.property);
        },{urls:["https://*/*"]});
    }).catch(()=>{});

})(chrome.storage.sync || chrome.storage.local);
```

**Read more**

1. Storage specs/firefox:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage
2. Storage spect/chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage
3. Permission requests/firefox:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Request_the_right_permissions

Comment: I've tried this (pre load into cache) but my background.js variables don't persist.

Comment: Show me your code, where it doesn't persist, I will try to help. If you will use the cache as I showed, it will persist. You can read it from cache and write it to storage, it will be persisted so.

Comment: I think I have understood your problem.
I have added an example of settings persist.
If you want to persist settings from background.js - you need to save it to storage, if you need to read it - you can read it from the cache. I have added ```settings.set(options,callback)``` to my examples. Now you can read the settings as ```settings.property``` and update it with ```settings.set(properties,callback);```